# C++ WINAPI Create Multiple Partitions on Mounted VHD

Tags: c++, winapi, ioctl, virtual-disk

I managed to create a VHD and attached it. Afterwards, I created a disk(IOCTL CREATE_DISK) and set its layout using IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX. Now, when I examine disk through Disk Management. I have a 14MB with a 7 MB partition, expectedly.

```
int sign = 80001;
CREATE_DISK disk;
disk.Mbr.Signature = sign;
disk.PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;

auto res = DeviceIoControl(device_handle, IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK, &disk, sizeof(disk), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
res = DeviceIoControl(device_handle, IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES, 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

LARGE_INTEGER partition_size;
partition_size.QuadPart = 0xF00;
DWORD driver_layout_ex_len = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX);
DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX driver_layout_info;
memset(&driver_layout_info, 0, sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX));

driver_layout_info.Mbr.Signature = sign;
driver_layout_info.PartitionCount = 1;
driver_layout_info.PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;

PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX part_info;
PARTITION_INFORMATION_MBR mbr_info;
part_info.StartingOffset.QuadPart = 32256;
part_info.RewritePartition = TRUE;
part_info.PartitionLength.QuadPart = partition_size.QuadPart/2 * 4096;
part_info.PartitionNumber = 1;
part_info.PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;

mbr_info.BootIndicator = TRUE;
mbr_info.HiddenSectors = 32256 / 512;
mbr_info.PartitionType = PARTITION_FAT32;
mbr_info.RecognizedPartition = 1;
part_info.Mbr = mbr_info;
driver_layout_info.PartitionEntry[0] = part_info;
auto res_layout = DeviceIoControl(device_handle, IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, &driver_layout_info, sizeof(driver_layout_info), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Now, how do I partitionize this disk into two partitions? I want to create another partition out of the unpartitioned part of the disk(the other half basically). It says in the documentation is that PartitionEntry is an array of variable size(No, it is not it is an array of size 1.) Do I call set layout IOCTL for every partition I want to create? If so, how do you go about that? Is multi-partitioning possible through WINAPI interface?

P.S: I am aware that people usually invoke diskpart for this line of work.

Edit:
Adding second partition two layout was messing my stack up so I took another route (heap).

```
DWORD driver_layout_ex_len = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX) + sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX); // one layout+partition + partition
PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX driver_layout_info = (PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX) std::calloc(1, driver_layout_ex_len);

driver_layout_info->Mbr.Signature = sign;
driver_layout_info->PartitionCount = 2;
driver_layout_info->PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;
// omitted here..
PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX part_info2;
part_info2.StartingOffset.QuadPart = 32256 + part_info.PartitionLength.QuadPart;
part_info2.RewritePartition = TRUE;
part_info2.PartitionLength.QuadPart = partition_size.QuadPart / 2 * 4096;
part_info2.PartitionNumber = 2;
part_info2.PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;

part_info2.Mbr = mbr_info;


driver_layout_info->PartitionEntry[0] = part_info;
driver_layout_info->PartitionEntry[1] = part_info2;
auto res_layout = DeviceIoControl(device_handle, IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, driver_layout_info, driver_layout_ex_len, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
auto res_err = GetLastError();
```

Since it was overriding my `device_handle` I could not IOCTL at all. This improvement eliminated that. Do not forget to pass driver_layout_info instead of &driver_layout_info after this change.

Comment: Hi Sıddık Açıl, I can reproduce this issue and find a workaround. Please check my answer to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi there, that one is a correct solution two. But, can you please add that defining layout_information_ex on heap is the way people do this generally? Since, there can be any number of partitions, instead of redefining it every time, allocating space for layout and extra partitions suffices.

Comment: Hi Sıddık Açıl, I'll consult the related engineer to find out the best practice of this issue. For the heap solution you can share it as an answer.

Comment: I added the solution to the question body. Looking forward to your update.

Comment: I'll update here if there is any progress.

Comment: I don't get it. I would expect writing the new partition table onto the disk with a WriteFile() on the handle.

Comment: No. The IOCTL works just fine. There is not need to manipulate the partition table. The error was me creatimg this variable on stack which caused it to get 192 bytes. However, an extra partition holds 144 bytes of memory. So if you index second or third partition entry, you are overwritinf you own stack which causes a huge mess. The solution is to allocate a space of size = sizeof(layoutinfostruct) + (partition_count-1)* sizeof(partitioninfostruct). Then pass it onto the input of ioctl

Comment: @SıddıkAçıl I update my answer and provide the suggested way for this issue. You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

> It says in the documentation is that PartitionEntry is an array of
>   variable size(No, it is not it is an array of size 1.)

"Some Windows structures are variable-sized,
beginning with a fixed header, followed by
a variable-sized array. When these structures
are declared,
they often declare an array of size 1 where the
variable-sized array should be." Refer to [@Raymond blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=38043).

Here [DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_drive_layout_information_ex) is an example:

```
typedef struct _DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX {
  DWORD                    PartitionStyle;
  DWORD                    PartitionCount;
  union {
    DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_MBR Mbr;
    DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_GPT Gpt;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
  PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX PartitionEntry[1];
} DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX, *PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX;
```

With this declaration, you would allocate memory for one such
variable-sized DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX structure like this:

```
PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX driver_layout_info = (PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX)malloc(FIELD_OFFSET(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX, PartitionEntry[NumberOfPartitions]));
```

You would initialize the structure like this (Use 2 partitions as example):

```
DWORD NumberOfPartitions = 2;
LARGE_INTEGER partition_size;
partition_size.QuadPart = 0xF00;

PARTITION_INFORMATION_MBR mbr_info;
mbr_info.BootIndicator = TRUE;
mbr_info.HiddenSectors = 32256 / 512;
mbr_info.PartitionType = PARTITION_FAT32;
mbr_info.RecognizedPartition = TRUE;

PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX driver_layout_info = (PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX)malloc(FIELD_OFFSET(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX, PartitionEntry[NumberOfPartitions]));
for (DWORD Index = 0; Index < NumberOfPartitions ; Index++) {

    driver_layout_info->PartitionEntry[Index].PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;
    driver_layout_info->PartitionEntry[Index].PartitionNumber = Index + 1;
    driver_layout_info->PartitionEntry[Index].RewritePartition = TRUE;
    driver_layout_info->PartitionEntry[Index].PartitionLength.QuadPart = partition_size.QuadPart / 2 * 4096;
    driver_layout_info->PartitionEntry[Index].Mbr = mbr_info;
}

driver_layout_info->Mbr.Signature = sign;
driver_layout_info->PartitionCount = 1;
driver_layout_info->PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;

driver_layout_info->PartitionEntry[0].StartingOffset.QuadPart = 32256;
driver_layout_info->PartitionEntry[1].StartingOffset.QuadPart = 32256 + driver_layout_info->PartitionEntry->StartingOffset.QuadPart;

DWORD driver_layout_ex_len = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX) + sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX);
```

Call `free(driver_layout_info);` after you use completely.

Comment: This was my first though actually. But, this code messes up your stack probably. See the [Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/p08ANv). It nearly overwrites everything you have previously defined on your stack which in my case overwrites device handles and stuff as soon as I execute `testInfo.element[1] = element1`.

Comment: I finally allocated my layout struct on heap to save my variables on stack. And, ran into ERROR_ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW exception possibly due to sum of partition lengths being larger than device capacity or I am missing something about MBR layout.